# Colorize an image using two parameters

Tags: plotting, graphics, image-processing

I have a matrix of data. I use

```
Colorize[Image[Rescale[data]],ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

to create an image from the data where the value of each pixel is used to pick a specific colour in the gradient colour scheme "Rainbow".

Now I want, to create an image where the value of each pixel is used as the opacity for a fixed gradient colour scheme from left to right. So, for instance, I want the left of the image to be blue and the right of the image to be red (in a continuous fashion). Then, when the a particular value of the matrix is high, the colour should be bright and when the value is low it should be dark.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = RandomReal[1, {30, 30}];

ImageMultiply[LinearGradientImage[{Blue, Red}, {30, 30}], Image[data]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's a little hard to be sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but at least it's a start. First, make the gradient image:

```
rainbowImg=Image[Colorize[Image[Rescale[Table[j, {i, 1, 100}, {j, 1, 100}]]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]]
```

[image]

Then take the data image and use it as an alpha channel to allow it to specify the brightness of the resulting image at each pixel. Since I don't have access to your data, just make it random.

```
dataImg=Image[Colorize[Image[Rescale[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}]]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]]
```

[image]

```
black = Image[ConstantArray[0, {100, 100}]];
Show[black, SetAlphaChannel[rainbowImg, dataImg]]
```

[image]

Since you asked that when "a particular value of the matrix is high, the colour should be bright and when the value is low it should be dark." I placed it against a black background (otherwise the transparent pixels would have appeared white on the screen).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [ColorCombine](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorCombine.html):

> When combining a color image with a grayscale image, ColorCombine creates an image of the same color space with alpha channel.

```
f1 = With[{dt = #, max = Last@Dimensions[#]}, ColorCombine[
       {Image[MapIndexed[List @@ ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, max}}][Last@#2] &, dt,{2}]],
        Image[dt]}, "RGB"]] &;

data = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];
im1 = Image[f1@data, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Append` to manually add the alpha channel:

```
f2 = With[{dt = #, max = Last@Dimensions[dt]}, 
         Image[MapIndexed[Append[List @@ ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, max}}][Last@#2], #1] &, 
               dt, {2}], 
         ColorSpace -> "RGB"]] &;
im2 = Image[f2@data, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{im1, im2}, Spacer[15]]
```

[image]

`Blend`ing `Blue` and `Red` instead of using `ColorData["Rainbow"]`:

```
f1b = With[{dt = #, max = Last[Dimensions[#]]}, 
    ColorCombine[{Image[MapIndexed[List @@ Blend[{Blue, Red}, Last[#2]/max] &, 
        dt, {2}]], Image[dt]}, "RGB"]] &;
f2b = With[{dt = #, max = Last[Dimensions[#]]}, 
    Image[MapIndexed[Append[List @@ Blend[{Blue, Red}, Last[#2]/max], #1] &, 
      dt, {2}], ColorSpace -> "RGB"]] &;

im1b = Image[f1b@data, ImageSize -> 300];
im2b = Image[f2b@data, ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{im1b, im2b}, Spacer[15]]
```

[image]